# how to make terminal resize to 20 lines in C?

Tags: terminal, font-size

I'm writing a terminal game build on `ncurses`.
I should ensure the window in suitable size.
How to adjust terminal window display 20 lines when running the process?
I think it should be use some C API.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
   int resizeterm(int lines, int columns);
```

to properly resize the terminal in ncurses.

## Edit

The OP wants to change the font of Terminal so

It's not really possible to adjust the terminal font using an ncurses. That's beyond the scope of ncurses. however if you're on mac :-) and this is where things become less portable, you can write a helper shell script that invokes applescript for mac os x ... .Have a look at [OSX: How can an application running in Terminal.app change the font size of its window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31778041/osx-how-can-an-application-running-in-terminal-app-change-the-font-size-of-its)

Comment: thanks.I have attempt it. Sorry for it only limit input area but adjust font size to filling whole terminal window. I'm on macOS and use zsh and setting TERM as xterm-256color, is the function  relative to terminal type?

Comment: It's not really possible to adjust the terminal font using an ncurses. That's beyond the scope of ncurses. however if you're on mac :-) and this is where things become less portable, you can write a helper shell script that invokes applescript for mac os x ... .Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31778041/osx-how-can-an-application-running-in-terminal-app-change-the-font-size-of-its

Comment: The script is works well! besides, do you have any idea to fit terminal just 20 lines?